# check for damaged file mp3, m4a (aac) in linux

Tags: linux, validation, audio, mp3, m4a

I have around 15,000 music files stored on Ubuntu server (16.04), around 50% FLAC, 25% each mp3 and m4a (aac).

I think maybe 3-5% are corrupted due to HDD hardware failure. The problems accumulated gradually for some time before I noticed. Files are now recovered to new drives using ddrescue.

Original storage was two copies of each file on separate devices, and both drives gradually failed, but independently. Result is that a file which is bad in one copy may be ok in the other copy.

I am trying to find command line validation tools to use in a script to identify which titles have at least one good copy. In cases where both are bad I will need to re-rip from cd.

For FLAC, I have looped the command `flac -t` in a script which generates lists of good files and the bad files. I believe the flac -t command decodes without sending audio to any play device, and calculates an MD5 hash on the decoded audio and compares this to an original hash included in the file’s metadata. This is pretty fast and works fine.

I would like to achieve similar validation with the mp3 and the m4a files, but have not been able to find a suitable tool. I have looked at mp3val, but testing this against an mp3 where I deliberately damaged data in the audio does not show an error.

From what I can find researching mp3 and m4a it seems there is no hash stored, so I am not sure what other approaches to validation might be possible.

Ideally I would like to sort into definitely good / definitely bad. If this can't be done,  I would still benefit from sorting into possibly good / definitely bad, or definitely good / possibly bad.

Can anyone suggest some linux tool that could achieve this, for either/both of mp3 and m4a/aac ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm afraid that some glitches are only audible, not an issue with data integrity in these formats.  Restore from backups?

Comment: @jww - well, strictly speaking I am writing a script and asking for suggestions for a suitable command to use in this script to achieve a desired effect. New to SO so not sure how narrowly the programming topic focus is usually applied. In any case, I have now duplicated the question on SuperUser here: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1268145/check-for-damaged-file-mp3-m4a-aac-in-linux?)

Comment: @Brad - actually, both backups and originals experienced some damage, so I am attempting to screen, to find one good copy of each title where possible. If all copies damaged, must re-rip from audio CD. In some cases file damage has affected metadata, in other cases audio data, such as playback dying halfway thru. Thus I am trying to first bulk-screen out obviously bad, playable files which must be scrapped/replaced. Suspect there are several hundred. Files with minor audio click/pop I can deal with later, when discovered by listening. But I think the FLAC test will even find these.

Comment: @BobM Hash everything between the backup and original, and where the hashes don't match, re-rip.

Comment: @Brad - Brilliant!. And I think I can improve the procedure further a bit, depending on whether no-match ends up a larger or smaller number of files. Assume no match will probably mean one good / one bad, less frequently both bad. If no match file count is not too huge, I can then just play/listen, and see if there is one good, thus avoid pain of re-rip. Thanks. will do this.